# in Game Logic, can Object A use Object B's sensor?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Is there a easy way for Object A to use Object Bs sensor using the logic bricks? or do I need to have an always sensor on Object A, and run a custom python script?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but, it looks like you just need to select both objects, and connect the sensor from objectB to a controller from objectA.

[image]

Comment: :P wow, I was trying to start using globalDict to save a global variable and have it play animation on the other object! This was almost to easy! thank you!